# Chrome Scrolling not working on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm having some really strange scrolling issues with Chrome (Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)) on Mac Os.

Firstly my various jquery and javascript functions weren't working correctly for me like `scrollTop()` `scrollBy()` and `window.scrollTo()`

To show the problems I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
#outter {
   height:5000px;
   background-color:grey;
   position:relative;
}

#inner1 {
   position:absolute;
   top:600px;
   height:100px;
   width:200px;
   background-color:red;
}

#inner2 {
   position:absolute;
   top:1200px;
   height:100px;
   width:200px;
   background-color:red;
}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("DD");
   window.scrollTo(0,600);
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="outter">
   <div id="inner1">
      hello1
   </div>

   <div id="inner2">
      hello2
   </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

To reproduce the problem perform the following:

1. open html - this should work correctly and scroll down to right location.
2. scroll down to the bottom of the window or other location.
3. reload the page by clicking the 'reload' button OR pushing enter on the URL bar after selection again.

I would have expected upon reloading the scroll would reposition however it doesn't. Operation in safari seems to work normally..

Am I doing something wrong here? Do other people get this behaviour?

Comment: Wow, this is two years old. I'm having the problem today. It happens in Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Opera Version:60.0.3255.170 but not Safari Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1) or Firefox 67.0.4 (64-bit). What did you do?

Answer (score 1):

I have chrome 57.0.2987.133  , i think it's a bug in chrome 57.0.2987.133 , it happens when you change scrollbar events , ex  clicking Facebook likes count , then when you exit it won't scroll anymore !